# No result with multiple array in Json with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

i create a code with JavaScript to fade Out and alert my results. but i don't know why this is now work can someone tell me what is problems?

with single data in array its work but with multiple data in array its not work!!!

php:

```
@$key  = $_POST['key'];

foreach ($key as $k)
{
    ...
    if ($affected_rows > 0) {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $mm = json_encode(array($k => '1'));
    } else {
        $mm = "2";
    }
}

return $mm;
```

JS:

```
for (var key in data) {   
    if( data[key] == '1'){
        $("#mrreq_"+key).fadeOut(1000);
        $.fn.success('','uid: '+key,'Delete');
    }else if (data[key] == '2'){
        $.fn.error('','uid: '+key,'Delete');
    }else {
         alert('error.');
    }

}
```

Edit:

console log with single array:

```
Object {654: "1"}
```

console log with multiple array is empty and nothing to show!!

Comment: what does console.log(data) give?

Comment: My problem resolver by changing  $mm to $mm[] . thanks to all